# Is arrangement of Animate.css and main.css files affecting functionality

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building my first website using Twitter Bootstrap, and have incorporated elements from an existing Bootstrap theme template into my HTML and CSS files in order to achieve a number of animation effects.

One of the effects that I am using is a `pulse` effect when hovering over a font-awesome `double-arrow-down` icon located inside `btn-circle`on my homepage. The styling for the desired 'pulsing' effect is located on `main.css`. Today I have since added a new file (`animate.css`) - which I am using to achieve some animation effects on my contact form at the footer of my page. However, it looks like the styling I had in place on `main.css` for the `hover:` pulse effect is being overwritten by what is on the `animate.css` file. When hovering over the `btn-circle` element on my homepage the pulsing effect is no longer working. When I remove `animate.css` the effect returns to normal.

I have tried adding `!important` to the below classes on `main.css` - but this does not appear to solve the issue. Is the order that I have the links to the css files in my `header` affecting the styling?

[Here is a link to my website](http://www.jonhowlett.uk)

[Here is the 'pulse' effect I would like to achieve](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-grayscale/)

Thanks

HTML:-

```
<head>
<title>Home | Jon Howlett</title>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat%Roboto:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<header class="intro" id="intro">
    <div class="intro-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1 class="brand-heading">Jon Howlett</h1>
                    <p class="intro-text">Aspiring web designer<br/>&amp; front-end developer.</p>
                    <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

main.css file:-

```
.btn-circle i.animated,
#nav-footer i.animated{
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-moz-transition-duration: 2s;
}

.btn-circle:hover i.animated,
#nav-footer:hover i.animated{
-webkit-animation-name: pulse;
-moz-animation-name: pulse;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
-moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.btn:hover {
background-color: #D35F45;
color: white;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
border: 2px solid #D35F45;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {    
0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {    
0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of your animation in your css file? because Animate.css has a pulse animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your pulse animation to avoid conflict names.

```
.btn-circle i.animate,
#nav-footer i.animate{
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-moz-transition-duration: 2s;
}

.btn-circle:hover i.animate,
#nav-footer:hover i.animate{
-webkit-animation-name: custom-pulse;
-moz-animation-name: custom-pulse;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
-moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.btn:hover {
background-color: #D35F45;
color: white;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
border: 2px solid #D35F45;
}

@-webkit-keyframes custom-pulse{    
0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {    
0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
}
```

And change the html to:

```
<a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animate"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've just tried pasting in the revised css but it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: I'm going to review this.

Comment: I'd be grateful if you mark my entry as the answer.